# Button with tag = 0 is not working

Tags: ios, swift

my problem is with the button with tag=0 .. all the buttons work fine, when i clicked on any button the previous thumb color goes to default (white) but if i click on the button with tag=0 then when i click on the next button, the button with tag 0 still red and doesnt change to default .. and then whole function refused to work correctly

here is the function 
any help pleeeeease

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->         UITableViewCell {

    var cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toWork") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = Berufs[indexPath.row]
    var btn:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10, 3, 40, 40))
    btn.tag = indexPath.row
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "setNew:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named:"transparent.png"), forState: .Normal)
    cell.indentationLevel = 1
    cell.indentationWidth = 45
    cell.addSubview(btn)
    btn.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    return cell
}

var old = 1000

func setNew(sender:UIButton)
{
    var tmpButton = view.viewWithTag(old) as? UIButton
    let btn = sender
    if (btn.backgroundColor == UIColor.redColor())
    {
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    else if (btn.backgroundColor != UIColor.redColor())
    {
        tmpButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        selection =  Berufs[sender.tag]
        println("you are a \(selection)")
    }
    old = btn.tag
    println("button tag is \(btn.tag)")
}
```

Comment: How about you don't use tags, but use proper MVC so that cells are configured according to their model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 is the default value for `tag`, so `view.viewWithTag(0)` probably returns something other than your button.

You should better start with 1, so

```
btn.tag = indexPath.row + 1
```

and handle your `old` counter accordingly.

---

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->         UITableViewCell {

    var cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toWork") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = Berufs[indexPath.row]
    var btn:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10, 3, 40, 40))

    btn.tag = indexPath.row + 1  // <-- HERE

    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "setNew:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named:"transparent.png"), forState: .Normal)
    cell.indentationLevel = 1
    cell.indentationWidth = 45
    cell.addSubview(btn)
    btn.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    return cell
}


var old = 1000

func setNew(sender:UIButton)
{
    var tmpButton = view.viewWithTag(old) as? UIButton
    let btn = sender
    if (btn.backgroundColor == UIColor.redColor())
    {
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    else if (btn.backgroundColor != UIColor.redColor())
    {
        tmpButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        selection =  Berufs[sender.tag - 1]   // <-- HERE

        println("you are a \(selection)")
    }
    old = btn.tag
    println("button tag is \(btn.tag)")
}
```

Comment: ok .. i'm sorry but i didnt get it .. how do suggest to edit this code .. thanx for ur help

Comment: i'm importing the strings from array using this tag which should also starts with 0

Comment: I have copied your code into my answer and marked the relevant lines with `// <-- HERE`. You need to avoid using the value `0` for the tag.

Comment: now it works .. i used ur advice and it works ... i only had to substract 1 from the `selection =  Berufs[sender.tag - 1]`  but also the red color after too many clicks starts to stay in more than one background :(

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag
```

> This method searches the current view **and all of its subviews** for the
>   specified view

So it can return anything with default tag==0. For example lable from button or something else

Answer (score -1):

By default, the button has a tag of 0.
I would suggest setting the tag to something like 100 + indexPath.row and then subtracting 100 from the tag of the UIButton on check.

Comment: i've been awake for sooo long .. how do u suggest to tdit the code above